# windows of apps opened with wine are very small and some barely visible

Tags: 20.04, gnome, wine, itunes

when trying to open itunes with wine 5.0 the window is very small and text can be barely seen because the window is almost fully black. other wine windows such as prompts from itunes and wine configuragtion windows are also small, but colors are displayed as usual. my system scaling is set to 125%, and I have tried cchamging the system theme to light to see if that would fix the color problems but that didnt work. itunes also cannot connect to any servers to log into apple id or update, but thats a problem for another post.

[example of small & black itunes window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J6RO.jpg)

Comment: iTunes won't work anyway so forget it.

Comment: Did you check at the Wine site to sere if the app even works with Wine? https://appdb.winehq.org/

Comment: @ChanganAuto really? i just followed a few guides and they showed it was possible

Comment: @David i did now, but the list is pretty small anyway and there are lots of other apps that do work but arent on the list.

Comment: Yes, it installs and runs most of the times but can't connect to the Apple device, being nothing more than a glorified media player of which you have dozens native.

Comment: Wine is not the do all everything works 100 percent thing many think it is.